# trying to expand out nodes to null parent

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm using **cytoscape.js** and **cytoscape.js-expand-collapse** to create dynamic hierarchies in my graph structure. I would like to be able to dynamically create a collapsed(merged) node that could potentially be expanded out, removed or possibly re-merged with additional nodes. I am having trouble whenever I call `nodes.move({parent:null})`. They become detached from the graph and I cannot re-attach them to a new parentNode. If I call `restore` on them I will see errors saying they already exist in the graph.

`merge` and `unmerge` by itself works fine in a simple case of no existing collapsed nodes. However calling merge on something that already contains a compound collapsed node breaks things. I would get the resulting merged node without the children of the previously collapsed merge candidate

**Update #1** I've realized my problem was returning the wrong moved nodes. Calling .move on a collection returns a new set of nodes. so the `unmerge` should return those instead.

**Update #2** cytoscape-expand-collapse utility does some internal book-keeping during the parent node collapse/expand by tucking away node data in 'originalEnds' data prop on the meta edges. so, if I'm now altering the graph dynamically by moving nodes in/out of parents these originalEnds pointers get out of sync causing infinite loops. I am doing some additional node tracking of my own as a workaround.

```
function merge(nodes){
    //if one of the nodes is a compound itself, first uncollapse, then merge
    var collapsed = nodes.filter(function(c){return typeof c.data('collapsedChildren')!=='undefined';});
    if (collapsed.length>0) {
        // for now just assume collapsed is a length of 1
        var unmerged = unmerge(collapsed); //unmerged should be now the former collapsed children
        nodes = nodes.subtract(collapsed).union(unmerged.nodes());
    }
    var parentNode = cy.add({group:'nodes', data: {id: parentID}});
    nodes.move({parent: parentID});
    collapseApi.collapse(parentNode);
    return parentNode;
}

function unmerge(parentNode){
    collapseApi.expand(parentNode);
    var children = parentNode.children();
    var moved = children.move({parent:null});
    //at this point children become "detached" from the graph
    // .removed() returns true, however, calling restore() logs an error and they are still technically in the graph
    parentNode.remove();
    return moved;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your updates on this tricky topic! When you find a working solution, consider posting it below, this way people will know your question is answered. You can also accept your own answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ele.move()` has a more convenient implementation in cytoscape>=3.4:  The elements are modified in-place instead of creating replacement elements.

Old code that uses the returned collection from `ele.move()` will still work.  New code can be simplified by not having to use the returned collections at all.